# Replace changes the value of the captured group

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var a = "x=>";
a = a.replace(/([^=]+)=>/, '(\1)=>');
alert(a);
```

I'm getting `()=>`, I was expecting the `a` after replace will be `(x)=>` as `x` is captured in the first captured group.

Why the back-reference `\1` does not work here?

Comment: `alert(x);` Waaaat is `x`? Where is it defined?

Comment: @Tushar well the result should be `(x)=>` as the captured group would be `x` but instead of `x` there is a square character there

Comment: sorry it should be `alert(a)`.

Comment: Yeah, so it might be putting an _octal_ `\1` in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get first capturing group, use `$1` in the replacement.

```
.replace(/([^=]+)=>/, '($1)=>');
                        ^^
```

`\1` - backreference is only available in the RegEx.

```js
var a = "x=>";
a = a.replace(/([^=]+)=>/, '($1)=>');
console.log(a);
```

Comment: thanks a lot. It worked but what is `\1` then? I remember that long time ago I used `$1` and someone just told me that in javascript `\1` is the first group

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani It's back-reference to refer to the string matched in the first captured group.

Comment: oh thats why that worked for me then. now I remember. thanks again